# Displaying the last page of posts

Tags: loop

I'm using a custom loop to display posts using pagination. My query shows 4 posts per page, and there are 4 pages, so 16 posts in total.
Is it possible to load in the last page of posts first? So when I load the query, it first shows page 4, then when I click 'show next' it shows page 3, et cetera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to load in the last page of posts first?

Order `DESC` instead of `ASC` and make use of the `posts_clauses` filter.

```
function wpse_59557_order_desc( $pieces ) 
{
    // Add conditionals here and abort in cases, where we don't want this, for e.g.:
    // if ( ! is_home() OR ! is_front_page() ) return;

    // We only want if to run once
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    return $pieces['orderby'] = 'DESC';
}
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse_59557_order_desc' );
```

---

### Explanation

The `posts_clauses` is the last filter in a series of filters (for e.g. `posts_where`), that allow the manipulation of the current query. If summons all tasks, the previous filters do: Modify the where/order/orderby/etc. pieces of the sql query. This filter allows a detailed modification of a default core query, and therefore helps avoiding another query for a single task.

#### When to use it

If you're in need of doing a task, that isn't possible by default and would bring you in the situation where you are about dismissing the first query and adding another one, then this filter can be used.

#### What to consider

This filter triggers for a lot of stuff. So always make sure to abort this filter in cases, where the modification is not needed/wanted. I also added a call to `remove_filter()` to avoid intercepting the query more than once. If you want, you can move the conditionals out of the function and wrap the `add_filter()` call in conditionals.

Comment: Thank you! Out of interest, what does posts_clauses do?

Comment: See edit & update of the answer.